# Extension for Pod class can't find the class

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

So I received a project from a client to perform a code review on. I can't get it to work though.

I am getting an error on an extension class for `Alamofire`, which is included using CocoaPods. The class contains an `import Alamofire` statement, so it is included. Cmd clicking the name of the class navigates to the `Alamofire` pod and the relevant class (`DataRequest`), so that works.

I have tried building the pods by themselves, to ensure they are built. I have also tried removing my DerivedData folder, but now I come up short with ideas.

How can I fix this?

Edit: It seems I get other errors about classes not being found, from other Pods and other simple references (not extensions), it looks like my pods are not being integrated in the compile process.

Edit 2: Think I found it:

> Target 'Pods-Project' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_Project.framework' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'

Comment: Clean maybe ? :) The version of Xcode is the same on both ends ?

Comment: @Lamasse I did a clean, no difference. I can't ask the Xcode version today, the guy is on holiday :)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the Pods folder, deleted the Podfile.lock file, cleared DerivedData and set the build settings of the pod project to build all archs, not only the selected ones, now it works!